# Unable to configure port in Redis database

Tags: redis, port, config, ubuntu-10.04, configure

I am trying to configure the ports in Redis database. I have changed the port number to 7778 in the `redis.conf` file. This file is in `etc\redis.conf`

And I'm using this command 
`redis-server /etc/redis.conf`

And this goes through. I'm able to get through.
However if I execute this command 
`redis-cli or redis-cli /etc/redis.conf`

I'm getting this error

> could not connect to redis at 127.0.0.1:6379:connection refused.
>   How is the first one getting through and not this.

Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thank you
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell redis-cli which port to connect to. If your redis server is running on 7778 then

```
redis-cli -p 7778
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working but I am getting an another error.

Comment: This is working thank you. However I'm ubable to ping the redis-cli. I'm getting this error : 127.0.0.1:7778> ping error NOAUTH Authenication required. Should I change this in the redis.conf file

Comment: Ping redis-cli???? Are you issuing ping command from redis-cli or from your application?